# How to create an exhaustive, non repeating set of sets of pairs of a given set?

Tags: combinatorics

Imagine a professional networking event. Let’s say you have 6 people attending, (A, B, C, D, E, F), and you want each person to be paired with each other person, in 5 rounds of interactions, with no dupes (so no two people are paired with the same person twice)

So your solution would look something like this

Round 1

(A, B) (C, D) (E, F)

Round 2

(A, C) (B, E) (C, F)

…

Round 5
(A, E) (B, C) (D, F)

(But with Rounds 3 and 4 as well).

My initial intuition says this should be possible, it’s possible when N is 2 (A, B), and when N is 4 (A, B) (C, D) || (A, C) (B, D) || (A, D) (B, C).
But I can’t find a solution when N is 6, and I wrote a quick program to test all possible solutions which couldn’t find one either. It’s possible the program has a bug, but I’m leaning more towards there isn’t a solution.

Questions for you!

1a) Can you find a solution
or
1b) Can you find a proof for why there is no solution

And

2. What’s the pattern in the more general case. (N people, N-1 rounds, where N is even). Are there Ns > 6 for which there is a solution? Is 6 the exception, or is it 2 and 4? Or are there some of each? (TBF this question might be a PHDs worth of work)
3. What is this kind of problem called? It’s in set theory/combinatorics, but is there a more specific field? Has someone already answered theses questions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, this problem is [edge coloring of a complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring) and it has one of my favorite "pictorial" proofs ever!

See the second illustration in the wiki page and lemme quote the relevant text:

> Soifer (2008) provides the following geometric construction of a coloring in this case: place n points at the vertices and center of a regular (n − 1)-sided polygon. For each color class, include one edge from the center to one of the polygon vertices, and all of the perpendicular edges connecting pairs of polygon vertices.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring#/media/File:Complete-edge-coloring.svg

Each color is a different round, and all the edges of that color are the pairings for that round.

In short, for even $N$, a perfect solution exists, so it does seem your program has a bug.  Also, for odd $N$, the best-possible solution (where one person sits out per round) also exists - simply add a dummy to convert to an even number.  Lemme know if you have trouble understanding the proof.

Comment: I figured there would be a model in graph theory. Thanks, this is it!